# SORACOM APIレスポンスのエラー一覧について

Tags: soracom

API呼び出しにおいて、エラーが戻ってくることがあります。例えばパラメーターに指定したIMSIが間違っていた時には下記のようなエラーコードおよびエラーメッセージが戻ってくるかと思います。

```
{"code":"SEM0001","message":"No such resource found"}
```

これらのエラーコードおよび原因（メッセージ）の一覧はどこかに記載されていますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問ありがとうございます。
エラーコードに関しては、3桁のコンポーネント文字列(SEMなど）と4桁の数値で構成しており、messageにはエラー内容が記載されております。messageに関しては、デフォルトでは英語文字を返しますが、リクエストヘッダーにX-Soracom-Lang:jaといれていただきますと、日本語対応文字がある場合は、日本語で内容を返します。

エラーコードの一覧に関しては、現在ドキュメントを作成しておりますので、お待ち頂ければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。